# Findstr command in for-loop stops after a certain line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this snippet of script:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"%SECTION%" /C:"%TARGET%" %BASE%') do (
    :: Stuff:
)
echo Search Parameters not found
```

...where `SECTION` and `TARGET` are two search parameters. The `BASE` file is approximately 16,000 lines.

Here's my problem:

When I execute the for-loop inside a batch script, it searches for 2397 lines exactly, then just gives up. However, if I run the `findstr` command manually, it will search all lines as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does it do when it `gives up`?  Error Message? Exit Code `ErrorLevel`?  Closes the cmd prompt? Have you tried running the script with `echo on` and in a cmd window?

Comment: I think you're reaching a buffer limit in the for command (but I can't find any documentation that proves/disproves this). Try redirecting the output of the `FINDSTR` command, an then using `FOR /F` on that file

Comment: @DavidRuhmann Yes echo was on, even added a variable to keep track of the last line it read. It just simply exits the for loop

Comment: How big (in bytes) is your %base% file?

Comment: @Endoro The size of the file is 650KB.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tested it with XP and win8, it doesn't work in a batch file. Do you want to put your question at a experts forum? If not, I will do this. Imo I'ts a memory issue.

Comment: In the mean time you can send the result from the command line to a temp file and parse the temp file.

Comment: add an answer and ill mark it

Comment: @Endoro go ahead and put the question there if you wish - let me know the results, though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fool's mistake - upon changes of versions, the location of a certain file shifted. So while I thought my search for the file was correct, it actually ended up retrieving a file in similar name, but not the same file (MotionBase.class.asasm vs what I needed: BASE.class.asasm)
Thought I checked the location before submitting this question, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fail for you?  It works here in Win 8 and a XP Pro VM to print 16,000 lines.

```
@echo off
(for /l %%a in (1,1,16000) do @echo 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789)>file
SET "section=123"
SET "target=456"
SET "base=file"

ECHO start
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /NC:"%SECTION%" /C:"%TARGET%" "%BASE%"') do (
ECHO %%a
)
pause
```